# objects, php, javascript errors

Tags: javascript, php

[Javascript Object to a PHP Object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pORFYsgOXog)

I was searching for the tutorial how to pass associative array from JavaScript to PHP object and found this video. I think it is a little bit old it was added in 2010. I tried it and had error. I ask you to help me to correct it or help me to to get php object from js object.

*index.php*

```
<script>
        let ar = new Array();
        ar["name"] = "name1";
        ar["name1"] = "name2";
        console.log(ar);

        function convertOb(object){
            var json = "{";
            for (property in object) {
                var value = object[property];

                if (typeof(value) == "string") {
                    json += '"' + property + '":"' + value +'",';
                } else{
                    if (!value[0]) {
                        json += '"' + property + '":"' + convertOb(value) + ',';
                    } else{
                        json+= '"'+ property +'":[';
                        for (prop in value) json+= '"' + value[prop] + '",';
                            json = json.substr(0,json.length-1) + "],";
                    }
                }

            } return json.substr(0,json.length-1) + "}";
        }

        let json = convertOb(ar);
        $.post("main.php", {json:json}, function(data){
              console.log(data);
        });
        
    </script>
```

*main.php*

```
<?php
        function jsonstring2obj($str){
            return json_decode(stripslashes($str));
        }

        $ar = jsonstring2obj($_POST['json']);  //error1
        echo $ar->name; //error2

    ?>
```

My errors:

Undefined index: json  //error1

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object  //error2

Comment: Why not use `JSON.stringify(ar)`? Also why are you setting named properties on an array?

Comment: Where I can use it?

Comment: Replace `let json = convertOb(ar);` with `let json = JSON.stringify(ar);`?

Comment: I have more complicated codes above it is just simply example and with that i can catch the idea

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined 
In console i had this error aafter changing

Comment: I don't see how the change I suggested would give that error since the variable `json` is being defined there. --- May you update the question with a true [mcve]? If the example doesn't show the error it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Make sure the question is edited rather than posting code in the comments.

Comment: $.post("main.php", {json:json}, function(data){
              console.log(data);
     });
line of this code calls error

Comment: The code posted in the question (and in the comments) does not throw any errors.